# The argument type 'TextDirection' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextDirection?'

Tags: flutter, dart

there is a simple TextField and I want to give it TextDirection the problem is that it i encounter the error i said

```
TextField(
   textDirection: TextDirection.RTL,
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was that the `easy_localization` package won't allow to use rtl in text direction.
I used it by importing tha package and adding its alias

`import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart' as localized;`

`localized.TextDirection.rtl`

**UPDATE 2024**

Instead of importing the other package just add this import:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

And edit your code this way:

```
textDirection: ui.TextDirection.rtl
```

Comment: Or you can do `import 'dart:ui' as ui;` then use it like this: `ui.TextDirection.rtl`

Comment: The comment above should be converted into an answer

Answer (score 3):

The [text direction class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextDirection-class.html) you are supposed to use has a constant value of `rtl`.

Whichever class you use there, that has a constant of `RTL` is the wrong one.

Comment: for my case it was `import 'package:intl/intl.dart'` that made it become RTL instead of rtl; I had imported it since of using a `DateTime`.
Simply changing that into `import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;` and referring to `DateTime` as `intl.DateTime` fixed the problem as not it does not override `rtl`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with easy_localization package so you need to do that

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart' hide 
TextDirection;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code use TextDirection.rtl insted of TextDirection.RTL go documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextDirection-class.html)

```
   TextField(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Name',
              hintText: 'Card Holder Name',
            ),
          ),
```

your result [image]